# Skewness of Random Data from rsn Function in sn Package

Tags: r

I am following the discussion presented in [How to sample from the SN and related distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sn/vignettes/how_to_sample.pdf), section 2.1. I have generated 100 random samples using the following code:

```
library(sn)
cp <- c(3,1.2,0.8)
dp <- cp2dp(cp, family="SN")
y <- rsn(100, dp=dp)
```

According to the description in the paper, this should generate random data with a skewness of 0.8 (gamma). However, when I calculate the skewness using `skewness()` from the *moments* library, I get a value of 0.43. I am trying to understand the discrepancy between the two values here. The paper does allude to the difference between gamma and alpha, but does not go into detail.

Fundamentally, my question is: How can I generate random data from a skewed normal (or skewed t) distribution where the output `skewness()` matches the input for the skewness to the random number generator function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot duplicate your problem. Since you did not set a random number seed it is impossible to replicate your exact results, but I get a much better fit. There are three different ways to define skewness. Unfortunately the documentation of the skewness function in package `moments` does not indicate which one it uses, but `e1071` and `DescTools` both provide skewness functions and let you choose which one you want:

```
set.seed(42)
cp <- c(3,1.2,0.8)
dp <- cp2dp(cp, family="SN")
y <- rsn(100, dp=dp)
moments::skewness(y)
# [1] 0.8892228
e1071::skewness(y)
# [1] 0.8759179
DescTools::Skew(y)
# [1] 0.8759179
```

The results are close and comparable to your expected value of .8. Selecting a larger sample will provide a closer fit:

```
set.seed(123)
y <- rsn(1000, dp=dp)
moments::skewness(y)
# [1] 0.8452521
e1071::skewness(y)
# [1] 0.8439846
DescTools::Skew(y)
# [1] 0.8439846
```

The `e1071` and `DescTools` package prefer the 3rd definition of skewness (see the documentation at `?e1071::skewness` and `?DescTools::Skew`). It appears that the `moments` package uses the first definition:

```
e1071::skewness(y, type=1)
# [1] 0.8452521
```